# matlab scientific notation issue

Tags: matlab, scientific-notation

I have an issue where an 8-digit string such as '313397E9' is being passed into excel, then read as the number '313397000000000', or '3.133970e+014'.

This is then being read by Matlab and recognized as the number, not the string. What would be the easiest way to convert it back to the 8-digit string?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: You are going to have to tell us the communication mechanism between MATLAB and Excel

Comment: it uses actxserver to open excel, then gets the specific sheet, then value=(sheet.Range(['A2:A32000']).value). That is all in a large base of code that I didnt write, and probably shouldn't mess with. Is there anyway to convert it back to the 8-digit once it's a number?

Comment: How are the numbers stored in MATLAB. Are they really strings? And how do you want them stored in Excel? Strings or numbers?

Comment: If you want to stop Excel converting to a number then I think you should be able to use notation like this: `'1234`

Comment: Nah, there is way too many excel spreadsheets to deal with. The numbers are stored in matlab as numbers in a cell array (all the other values in the cell array are strings, as they should be).

Comment: I've tried num2str(value,'%E') but that gives me 3.133970E+014. If I could only get the string with the right exponentiation, I could parse it.

Comment: See also: http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/5/80

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Regular expressions to the rescue!](http://xkcd.com/208/) You can use [REGEXPREP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexprep.html) to convert the trailing zeros into Ex, where x is the number of zeros you just replaced.

```
%# convert the number to a string
nn = num2str(3.133970e+014)

nn =
313397000000000

%# replace zeros using regexprep
regexprep(nn,'([0]*)','E${num2str(length($1))}')
ans =
313397E9
```

This also works if `nn` is a cell array of strings, btw, so you can convert your list of numbers in one go.

Comment: Do you recover 313390000000000.0 into 313390E9 or 31339E10?

Comment: works perfectly! Actually, good point, Jouni... I guess there is no way of knowing what the value was supposed to be in the first place...

Comment: @Jouni: 313390000000000 is converted to 31339E10 - not sure whether that's the OP really intended. Of course, if the idea was to always have 6 digits followed by E9, then everything would be fairly trivial. Also, 313390000000000.0 would be converted to 313393E10.E1. However, this input should not occur if you start with a number like 3e+014. If necessary, this could be fixed in the regexp, of course.

Comment: The string could be either 313390E9 or 31339E10, but excel would convert both to 3.13E+14. It is more likely that the E is towards the end, though, so I think I'm going to use Jonas' solution rather than modify 5000 spreadsheets.